# Aligning components with each other in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

A WPF application consists of a uniform grid of arbitrary size.  Each cell in the grid contains a canvas. Each canvas is a target for a drag and drop operation.

When I drag another canvas and drop it onto a canvas inside the grid I want the top left corners of the dragged canvas(source) and the target canvas to align, essentially placing the source on top of the target. The behaviour I'm looking for is a snap-to-grid effect.

Currently when I use `element.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)` the result in NaN. The problem is to determine the position of the corner for a canvas inside the grid, but relative to the entire window.  I would prefer to use the grid, as it automatically resize as the window resize.

Is it possible to get the actual position of a canvas inside a grid even when the grid size changed or alternatively specify a canvas to be aligned to another canvas inside the grid?

Comment: Try `Point p = yourCanvas.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), Window.GetWindow(yourCanvas));`

Comment: You should be able to get the relative position by [TransformToAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608865.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by drawing each canvas onto another canvas by specifying the top and left properties of the canvas, I had to scratch the grid.  I specified the position of every canvas by using

```
Canvas.SetLeft(Me, position.X)
Canvas.SetTop(Me, position.Y)
```

where `Me` is an instance of the canvas.

It is now easy to get the top and left properties of every canvas.  The only problem now is I have to implement the resizing of every canvas manually.